# I need to get id from a knockout foearch and pass in a form

Tags: laravel, knockout.js

I need to get id from a knockout `foreach` and pass in a form

```
< data-bind="foreach: {data: sourceItems, afterRender: lazyLoadImage}" class="col-sm-8">  

  {{Form::open(array('url' => '/movies/$data->id/reviews'))}}
```

$data->id or $data.id or +id+ not work

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

Its not like i am even sure about what you are asking BUT despite that minor detail i do have a solution for you

```
  {{Form::open(array('url' => '/movies/' + $data.id + '/reviews'))}}
```

or

```
  {{Form::open(array('url' => '/movies/' + $data.id() + '/reviews'))}}
```

Try them out and let me know

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to mix client-side and server-side templating; that's not going to work.

`{{Form::open(array('url' => '/movies/$data->id/reviews')}}` is going to be evaluated on the server literally. The knockout context only exists once the app has started in the browser. You probably want to use laravel *or* knockout, not both.